# Is safe to use TransactionScope in Web Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, transactionscope

I have a big - and randomly problem when using `TransactionScope` in web application:

I have a web application, which has some methods that uses transactions:

```
public class ProductsService
{
    private readonly ProjectDbContext _db;
    public ProductsService(ProjectDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void DelteProduct(Guid product_Id)
    {
        Product product = _db.Products.First(p => p.Id == product_Id);

        using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
            // Delete comments
            _db.SaveChanges();

            // Delete subscriptions
            _db.SaveChanges();

            // Delete product
            _db.SaveChanges();

            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it locally, i had no problems.

However, when i moved the project into production, i randomly get `SqlExceptionTransaction` error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlExceptionTransaction (Process ID 55) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.
Rerun the transaction.
```

I thought transactions should work in a queue, and new Transactions should wait until older ones are committed, and not blocking them - even if an error occurs.

1. Why i am getting this error?
2. Should i avoid using Transactions at all in web applications?
3. I am using `TransactionScope` wrong?

Comment: Why do you need `TransactionScope` here at all?

Comment: This is a simple example. I need to make sure that all related entries are deleted successfully and not have orphaned data in database

Comment: if `ProjectDbContext` is EF context, than `SaveChanges` is transactional itself. You shouldn't use the scope this way.

Comment: I know this, but on delete i need to commit changes sequential in order to avoid database `Reference Keys` exceptions. The example is simpler, normally i delete other entries as well.

Comment: > i need to commit changes sequential - you should post more details about this. I can't imagine a case with EF, when one should match deletion sequence to delete entries from store.

Comment: Because of the database structure, I can't have `Cascading delete` on all the entries - i need to delete items in sequential order. First comments, then subscriptions, then the product itself. This is tested, i just need to use `Transaction` in order to make sure everything gets deleted

Comment: TransactionScope is fully safe, but it can implicitly create locks which can lead to deadlocks in multi-thread environements for example. The deadlocks occurs because of something more specific in your code we can't see here. Google for deadlock to understand what it is and to determine how to diagnose your specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought transactions should work in a queue, and new Transactions should wait until older ones are committed, and not blocking them - even if an error occurs.

Transactions queue, but only if *possible*. A deadlock occurs when two transactions wait for each other; both holding onto resources required by the other. There are tons of articles out there describing deadlocks and how they can occur in a database.

> Why i am getting this error?

If you want to see what is causing the deadlock you can profile your database and analyze the deadlock graph (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/). As a general note, I would avoid using the TransactionScope default constructor because it sets the transaction level to serialized (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx).

From the article:

> In SQL Server SERIALIZABLE transactions are rarely useful and extremely deadlock-prone.  Put another way, when the default READ COMMITTED isolation level does not provide the right isolation semantics, SERIALIZABLE is rarely any better and often introduces severe blocking and deadlocking problems".

---

> Should i avoid using Transactions at all in web applications?"

By all means, no. Transactions should be used to define atomic operations, things that *must* be committed as one should run in one transaction. There is nothing special about web-applications in that retrospect, but: stop using the default constructor.

> I am using TransactionScope wrong?"

As I explained above: yes, avoid the default constructor and be specific about your transaction level; "Serialized" is never the right answer

Comment: > You are using pessimistic locking all over the place - what is your point based on?

Comment: I am assuming that this is not the only place he is using a TransactionScope with a default constructor

Comment: How `TransactionScope` defaults are related to concurrency mode (pessimistic or optimistic)?

Comment: Yes, the default TransactionScope ctor sets the transaction level to "Serialized", this is the same as pessimistic locking.